# Postdoc in Paris with foreign funding

Tags: funding, postdocs, france, contract, eu

I am moving to Paris for a postdoc in spring 2021 and I have received funding from Denmark for two years. I am considering whether administering the grant myself or having it administered by INSERM. I would like to have detailed information on how the salary will be calculated in each case and how to get a work contract and social security, as well how to pay taxes in case I administer the grant myself. I know in other places this kind of contract would be a visiting researcher contract. I am an EU citizen (IT). I do not speak French at the moment but I am starting language classes. Any useful link for where to gather information for this situation would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Contact your supervisor, and ask them to direct you to the person(s) in the French university who can answer your questions.

Comment: I have already done this, but it is really difficult to communicate with the administration. I wonder whether there is a source of information online for foreign researchers in my situation.

Comment: It is my experience in France that most things are arranged in person. I doubt that there are resources online that can give you all the information you need, and I think your best bet is to talk to administration, possibly with help from a future group member. Also, it is (almost) always hard to do administration in a foreign country. In any case I cannot help you further, but I can wish you the best of luck!

Comment: We don't really do requests for "useful links," so closing this for now. If you like, you could rephrase the post to ask your question directly and then flag for reopening.